# Why can R not find the value of an argument through lexical scoping?

Tags: r, function, arguments, lexical-scope

I have been reading Hadley Wickham's Advanced R in order to gain a better understanding of the mechanisms of R and how it works behind the scene. I have so far enjoyed it and everything is quite clear. There is one question that occupies my mind for which I have not yet found an explanation.
I am quite familiar with the scoping rules of R which determine how values are assigned to FREE VARIABLES. However, I have been grappling with the question of why R cannot find the value of a formal argument through lexical scoping in the first case. Consider the following example:

```
y <- 4
f1 <- function(x = 2, y) {
  x*2 + y
}

f1(x = 3)
```

It normally throws an error because I didn't assign a default value for argument `y`. However, if I create a local variable `y` in the body of the function it won't throw any error:
I also read in Professeur Matloff's book that arguments act like local variables, so that's why this question remains a mystery for me.

```
f1 <- function(x = 2, y) {
  y <- 4
  x*2 + y
}

f1(x = 3)
```

And also here there is no error and it is quite clear why:

```
y <- 2
f2 <- function(x = 2) {
  x*2 + y
}

f2()
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: To add extra info, it also doesn't error out if `y` is not used at all `f1 <- function(x = 2, y) {x*2}; f1(x = 3)`

Comment: Yes indeed dear @thelatemail that's because of lazy evaluation :)

Comment: Yes, a consequence of lazy evaluation.  Only when `y` is called will it throw the error. In the second example, `y` is defined before it's called.  And in your comment example, it's never called, so no error.

Comment: @TechCommodities Yes indeed, I also edited my question added another example. Just I was wondering what difference an argument would make if they are to act as local variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that R will only throw the error when you go to use the variable. if you had

```
f1 <- function(x = 2, y) {
  x*2 + 5
}

f1(x = 3)
# [1] 11
```

everything would be fine. That's because the parameter is a "promise" which isn't resolved till you actually use it. This allows you to do things like

```
f1 <- function(x = 2, y=x+5) {
  x*2 + y
}

f1(x = 3)
# [1] 14
```

Where the `y` value will actually use the value of `x` that's passed to the function when the promise is evaluated. Furthermore you can also do

```
f1 <- function(x = 2, y=z+2) {
  z <- x + 10
  x*2 + y
}

f1(x = 3)
[1] 21
```

Where `y` is able to take the value of `z` that didn't even exist when the function was called. Again this is because the parameter values are promises and are only evaluated when they are actually used. They have access to all the values in the environment when they are evaluated. But note that this only works because default parameter values are evaluated in the context of the function body. This is different than when you pass in a value to a function. In that case the value is evaluated in the calling environment, not the local function body. So you can't do

```
f1(x = 3, y=z+2)
# Error in f1(x = 3, y = z + 2) : object 'z' not found
```

The the reason you get the error in your first function is that a value for `y` does not exist when you try to use it in `x*2 + y`. Since you've defined `y` as a parameter, it is no longer a "free" variable and will not be looked up in parent scope. You don't get an error in your second function because you've re-bound the `y` variable to a local function variable so you are never using the parameter value at all.

If you ran

```
f1 <- function(x = 2, y) {
  y <- 4
  x*2 + y
}

f1(x = 3, y=200)
# [1] 10
```

The 2000 basically disappears. You no longer have access to that value after you reassign `y`. R does not check if a variable exists already before redefining so there is nothing that will try to evaluate the promise value `y` of the function parameter.

Arguments will act like local variables once the promise has been evaluated.

Comment: Thank you very much dear @MrFlick for this detailed and vivid explanation. In case of my first example, can I rephrase it like since I didn't provide a value for `y` and normally in this case the function looks for a value in its execution environment as is the case for default argument evaluation, so it throws an error?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you are saying. If you define `y` as a parameter to your function, then it will exist as a promise. In that case `y` is no longer a free variable. If you never supply a value for `y`, then when the promise is evaluated, it will discover it is "missing" and throw the error. You can check for missing parameters with the `missing()` function.

Comment: I understand it now, since it is not a free variable it won't be looked up in the parent environment, I just don't know how to thank you as you have always provided insightful answers to my questions and you are definitely one of my greatest inspiration here. Thanks indeed.

Comment: The rules are different if the promise comes from the a default parameter value or if a value is passed to the function. If the value comes from a default parameter value, then the promise is evaluated in the function's environment, if it's passed to the function then the promise is evaluated in the function's calling environment.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I understand it now. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 3):

I'd argue that R is quite consistent here.
As long as `y` is not called, R does not bother with this thing called promise.

```
f1 <- function(x = 2, y) {
  x*2 + 5
}

f1(x = 3)
# [1] 11
```

In your first example, y cannot be derived from the global environment since y is defined locally inside of the function environment. Since the value is missing, an error is thrown

```
y <- 4
f2 <- function(x = 2, y) {
  x*2 + y
}

f2(x = 3)
#> Error in f2(x = 3) : argument "y" is missing, with no default
```

This can lead to situations like this which can "hide" an error-prone setting until a user accidentally stumbles over it.

```
f3 <- function(x = 2, y) {
  if (x >= 2) {
    y <- 4
  }
  x * 2 + y
}

f3(x = 2)
#> 8
```

Such cases are hard to cover with unit tests which is why you often see functions with `force()` on top of their body.

```
f4 <- function(x = 2, y) {
  force(y)
  
  if (x > 2) {
    y <- 4
  }
  x * 2 + y
}

f4(x = 2)
#> Error in force(y) : argument "y" is missing, with no default
```

There is a nice [blog post](https://colinfay.me/lazyeval/) that covers lazy evaluation quite extensively.

Comment: Thank you very much dear @mnist for this great and detailed explanation. Unfortunately I can only accept one answer here :)